# Putting all the same value indices into one row

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data frame lets say

```
          A       B 
Date
2017      "hsd"   23
2017      "sn"    32
2016      "feh"   43
2016      "ak"    23
```

I want to manipulated it so it looks like this based on the same index

```
       A      B    A     B
Date  
2017  "hsd"  23   "sn"   32
2016  "feh"  43   "ak"   23
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction or show me how to do it based on this sample dataframe. 
At first I thought it was a transpose but that doesn't actually work

Comment: Can you have more than two rows with the same date? If so do you expect to create n columns if there are n rows with the same date?

Comment: @GoodDeeds yes and I expect 2n columns because you create a new column with A and its value and B and its value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
new_df = (df.assign(labels = df.groupby(level = 0).cumcount())
            .groupby([df.index,'labels']).first()
            .unstack('labels')
            .sort_index(axis =1,level = 1)
            .droplevel(1,axis = 1))
print(new_df)
          A   B     A   B
Date                     
2016  "feh"  43  "ak"  23
2017  "hsd"  23  "sn"  32
```

**Step by step**

**Step 1 [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)**

We need create a Series 
to distinguish the rows by each unique value in the index,
we will use this series to then convert each row by each unique index value into columns

```
print(df.assign(labels = df.groupby(level = 0).cumcount()))
          A   B  labels
Date                   
2017  "hsd"  23       0
2017   "sn"  32       1
2016  "feh"  43       0
2016   "ak"  23       1
```

**Step 2 [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html)**

Now we groupby using the new serie label and the index and then we use first() to create a MultiIndex,

```
print((df.assign(labels = df.groupby(level = 0).cumcount())
            .groupby([df.index,'labels']).first()))
                 A   B
Date labels           
2016 0       "feh"  43
     1        "ak"  23
2017 0       "hsd"  23
     1        "sn"  32
```

**Step 3 [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)**

Now We use unstack to get the expected DataFrame

```
print(df.assign(labels = df.groupby(level = 0).cumcount())
        .groupby([df.index,'labels']).first()
        .unstack('labels'))
            A         B    
labels      0     1   0   1
Date                       
2016    "feh"  "ak"  43  23
2017    "hsd"  "sn"  23  32
```

**Step 4 [`DataFrame.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with [`DataFrame.droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html)**

We sort the columns and drop level labels

```
          A   B     A   B
Date                     
2016  "feh"  43  "ak"  23
2017  "hsd"  23  "sn"  32
```

---

**Why my DataFrame is bigger ?**

As long as there are not the same number of entries for each year, null values ​​are generated, then I show you a simple example

```
df2 = df.iloc[0:-1]

print(df2)
          A   B
Date           
2017  "hsd"  23
2017   "sn"  32
2016  "feh"  43

new_df = (df2.assign(labels = df2.groupby(level = 0).cumcount())
            .groupby([df2.index,'labels']).first()
            .unstack('labels')
            .sort_index(axis =1,level = 1)
            .droplevel(1,axis = 1))
print(new_df)
          A     B     A     B
Date                         
2016  "feh"  43.0   NaN   NaN
2017  "hsd"  23.0  "sn"  32.0
```

**so 2x3 is Now 4x2**

Comment: Isn't there a loss of data tho? Let's say it was a 692x2 df. Almost half the data is lost from this. Or is there something I'm not seeing?

Comment: if there are 692 rows, information would not be lost since then labels would go from 0 to n where n is the size of each value repeated in the index. For example if you have 262 times 2016 then labels goes from 0 to 261 and would create 261 columns for that value in the index

Comment: I ran it and it went from 692x2 to 8x306

Comment: 8x306 is more than 692x2, do you have null values?

Comment: it is normal for you to have more values ​​simply because for example if for 2018 there are 10 rows and for 2016 there are only 2 rows then all the columns from 3 to 10 for 2016 are empty

Comment: please check section : `Why my DataFrame is bigger ?`

Comment: I am glad to help:)

Comment: Just to follow up. The NaN values I was getting was because of some other issue w/ how I was inserting values into my dataframe so this caused most of my confusion about the shape. But now it perfectly lines up! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way need a additional key create by `cumcount`

```
s=df.assign(num=df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()).set_index('num',append=True).stack().unstack(level=[1,2])
num       0         1    
          A   B     A   B
Date                     
2016  "feh"  43  "ak"  23
2017  "hsd"  23  "sn"  32
```

Comment: can you explain what's happening here? a solution like this works but appears daunting to interpret to beginners or even intermediate `pandas` users

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```py
df=df.stack().reset_index().groupby("Date").apply(lambda x: pd.concat([pd.Series({col: val}) for col, val in zip(x["level_1"], x[0])], axis=0))
```

Output:

```py
        A   B   A   B
Date
2016  feh  43  ak  23
2017  hsd  23  sn  32
```

Comment: You should see as much ```A``` and ```B``` as you get per year

Comment: Right but this doesn't append a new column when I ran it, it just spits out all the values that match the date

Comment: Yes, it recalculates everything every time you run it, and you want to be able to add new columns ```A``` and ```B``` ad hoc too ?